# How to lock as in, prevent change to an uploaded file

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I am working on a web application where file uploads and revisions are tracked.  Once a project is ready, it is submitted for an approval process.  I want to, upon "submit for approval" lock down all the projects attached files to prevent further changes.

The file uploads are handled by my own simple forms, and the files are tracked in a mySql db.

Is there anyway to set the files as read only so they can not be deleted, renamed, moved, etc. But still be viewed? (prevent change even by FTP or a cPanel file manager)

The idea is to protect the integrity of what has been approved. At the least I will be using .htaccess to prevent viewing the uploads folder directly.

Obviously, someone could SSH into the server and SUDO SU and do whatever, but, I am thinking for the less tech savy folks who need GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want application level control, not operating system level control. I.e., don't set the files to read only. Instead, have your application recognize that the project is in "submitted" status, and disable the features that would allow a user to change them.

If you're worried about somebody changing files with FTP or cPanel outside the project app then you likely have a personnel issue, not a technical one. I'm never a fan of using technology to solve a personnel issue.

That said, to additionally ensure that no OS-level changes have occurred, you can generate a hash of the contents of all the component files at the time the project is submitted, and then store those hashes in the database along with the project data. This will allow you, at any later date, to determine if the files have changed since.

Comment: It is more of an audit trail then a personnel problem.  thanks for the idea of storing the hash, that'll do!